# How can I scroll to a position in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to scroll to a position in my page, without using animation or anchors.

```
$(window).scrollTop(1000);

$(document).scrollTop(1000);

$('body').scrollTop(1000);

window.scrollTo(1000,0);
```

None of the above work, could someone please show me a correct example?

Comment: It should work if you have included the jQuery library in your page (*before calling the `.scrollTop` method*). It can also be affected by the design of your page (*you need to find the element with the scrollbars and apply the scroll to that element*).

Comment: The [first](http://jsfiddle.net/gj0btmbh/) [two](http://jsfiddle.net/fjrmx1zx/) definitely work! The last one you just have the params the wrong way round for vertical scrolling `window.scrollTo(0,1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript you can set the scroll doing this:

```
window.scroll(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.scrollTo(100,200)
```

The first argument is for x (Horizontal coordinate)

The 2nd argument is for y (Vertical Coordinate)